# How to send custom user input field with Paypal Subscription

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using Paypal subscription wizard to generate a javascript snippet for monthly recurring payments.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/

The javascript looks as following (modified senstive info):

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=esdasdcgmGsadsad34324hvfD7boV-2PMY34324234234234R7MjasdAUhH_qbIy4A&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'blue',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': 'P-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID);
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I added an input text above paypal subscription  buttons:

```
<input type="text" id="your_unique_username" value="Enter your user name">
```

All I am trying to do is pass the value the user placed in the input text object to paypal subscription and receive that value via email which i receive on every subscription or even better at paypal subscription dashboard where you see subscribed users.

Seems like a pretty straight forward feature to have, but haven't found any examples.
What would be the best method to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a `custom_id` variable, set to the value of an expression that will be evaluated when the button is clicked.

```
'plan_id': 'P-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
'custom_id': document.getElementById('your_unique_username').value
```

Comment: Okey, nice one, did check and it does show that custom_id in the subscription details on paypal which is great, however, i won't send that field via email.